# Performance Impact using SignalR in Web Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, signalr

On large Asp.net web application using SignalR for realtime notification impact performance. What can be better option for notifications

Comment: SignalR impacts the performance of what? Under what basis are you saying that? By running which code is the performance affected?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've tried, what the expected output was, and what your problems are. - SO is also not a place for getting library suggestions, that is up to you to do.

Comment: SignalR impact on IIS server and network, using SignalR there's realtime connection. I want to know, how much of this really impact servers and application.

Comment: @BabuGoli Well, you'd have to run it and see. Or look for anecdotal evidence on the Internet. Stack Overflow isn't for these types of questions.

Comment: Eric Lippert's rant seems appropriate: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 2):

SignalR is being rewritten; if you're seeing performance issues, it will be *very much worthwhile* looking at the upcoming release. Yes, the original version can have some perf limits.

But to answer you question: *at the moment*, raw web-sockets can be implemented far more scalably than SignalR, but it is a *lot* of work. We currently run 600,000 active connections just fine on a very small amount of servers using NetGain (available OSS), but: it isn't pretty. NetGain is *also* being rewritten using the same technology as the SignalR rewrite.

Comment: thanks marc. nice info. thats what I'm looking for. I'll look into NetGain. As small startup. we need to look at everything interm of cost

Comment: @BabuGoli but... what size are you looking for? Seriously, SignalR vCurrent should be fine for most folks, and vNext wipes the floor with vCurrent while making disparaging comments in its direction - it is pretty good. We (the folks using NetGain) have... *unusual* requirements